# How can I add an icon to the column title so that the icon is displayed in the popup edit?

Tags: kendo-ui

I want to add an icon to the column title in a kendoGrid table. It is important to me that the icon is displayed in the edit popup. Therefore the headerTemplate cannot be used.
This works so far. If now groupable: true is added, header attributes are displayed in the title.
My example code: https://dojo.telerik.com/OzuQIHef/4

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
 editable: "popup",
 groupable: true,
 columns: [{
  field: "name",
  title: "Name"  + " <span class=\'k-icon k-i-info\' ></span>",
  },{ command: "edit" }
 ],
 dataSource: [ { name: "Jane Doe" }, { name: "John Doe" } ],
});
```

How can I add an icon to the column title so that the icon is displayed in the popup edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is: https://dojo.telerik.com/OzuQIHef/6

The title must stay a string.

For the header, I used [headerTemplate](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.headertemplate).

For the label in the editor, I used the [grid edit event](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/edit) .

For the group indicator, I copied the CSS style that adds the "i" to ".k-i-info".